# How can a child element of Vertical Layout Group fit its Parent in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an app that is optimized for all screen sizes (basically for Android) in Unity. For that purpose, I am using Vertical Layout Group so that elements are placed properly in Stack Layout and don't overlap in different Screen Resolutions.

I have Parent Element that is stretched throughout the screen setting Anchor Stretch to Top = Bottom = Left = Right = 0. The Parent has a Vertical Layout Group Component. Then I have a Child element. I need to stretch it to fit its parent ie. stretch throughout the Screen. I have set my Game Resolution to 480x800. Now when I Increase the resolution to suppose 1920x1080, the Child Image shrinks its size. I want it to fit its parent that is stretched throughout the screen width & height.

Here are the Screenshots for reference.

**At 480x800 Resolution (Parent Element)**

[image]

**At 480x800 Resolution (Child Element)**

[image]

**At 1920x1080 Resolution (Child Element)**
Here the problem arises when the resolution increases. I want the Child Element to be stretched and must fit its Parent.

[image]

Comment: Does checking "Width" and/or "Height" under "Control Child Size" on the Vertical Layout Group achieve what you want?

Comment: @joll05, No, It doesn't work mate.